# How to post oauth API for login using Retrofit 1.9.0 in Android

Tags: android, oauth, retrofit

I have done successfully registration using below API but I'm not able to login 
got error message from server Retrofit:

```
{"code":401,"message":"Authentication failed","error":{"reason":"authError"}
```

This is my interface:

```
public static final String BASE_URL= "http://ashwinku.fwd.wf/ssng-project/api";
public static final String REGISTER_OPERATION = "/registerUser";
public static final String LOGIN_OPERATION = "/loginUser";
```

This is my User(Bean) Class for login:

```
public User(String firstName, String password) {
    this.firstName=firstName;
    this.password = password;
}
```

This is my Login fragment:

```
private void loginuser(String firstName, String password) {

     RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();

    //Creating object for our interface
    RequestInterface api = restAdapter.create(RequestInterface.class);
    user = new User(firstName,password);
    user.setFirstName(firstName);
    user.setPassword(password);
    //Defining the method insertuser of our interface
    api.loginuser(user, new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void success(User result, Response response) {
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            //An string to store output from the server
            String output = "";
            try {
                //Initializing buffered reader
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getBody().in()));
                //Reading the output in the string
                output = reader.readLine();



            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Displaying the output as a toast
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```

I using 1.9.0 retrofit but not able to login. Please help. It gives me error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
  api.loginuser(user, new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void success(User result, Response response) {
         //Try to get response body
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getBody().in()));

        String line;

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    String result = sb.toString();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

Also i just noticed that **you are getting 401 error code, which means - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials**

So that could be the problem too, you need to fix that on your side.

hope it helps

Comment: sir i m able to fetch api in output variable. and i m passing only two parameter firstName and password. but still getting error

Comment: are you constructing full url request? something like this .. `http://ashwinku.fwd.wf/ssng-project/api/registerUser/loginUser?username="puja"&password="123"` ?? the structure should be like this..and i m not sir, i m practically of your same age haha

Comment: does it work or not? Also 401 means, you are passing wrong information .. so you need to fix exact URL (if wrong ) and pass right information, you will get 200 response.

Comment: no, that not work and i m passing same info.and please look at this:

Comment: public static final String LOGIN_OPERATION = "/loginUser" how do i hard coad here. and that not is worked

Comment: there is any way to post oauth API using retrofit 1.9.0

Comment: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client - refer this, you will get all necessary information

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123263/discussion-between-puja-singh-and-ajay-p-prajapati).

Comment: hey.. come in group chat :)